# What does x-bit binary number means?

Tags: memory-management

What does x-bit binary number mean?
for example:

if **x = 8**

is **8-bit** means:
any number consists of **8** bits, like : **10101110**

or it has another meaning??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct. An x-bit binary number can be expanded as "A number in the [binary system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) that consists of x [binary digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)".

Comment: when we say algorithm generates 64bit random (binary)numbers, is that means its outputs' length is only 64bits. OR it means its outputs' range is from 0 to (2^64)-1, with any length?

Comment: From my post, a 64-bit binary number would be a number in the binary system consisting of 64 bits.